# How to overload a library class using es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have in my projet different objects that extends some other object caming from a library. 
The object of the library extends the Object class of the library.

So we have the following architecture :

```
// The library object class
class Object {

}

// The library object1 class that extends object library class
class Object1 extends Object{

}

// The library object2 class that extends object library class
class Object2 extends Object{

}


// My object class that extends Object1 library class
class MyObject extends Object1{

}

// My second object class that extends Object2 library class
class MySecondObject extends Object2{

}
```

My question is, how can I use es6 syntax to add a method in the 'Object' Class of the library i use without modify the code of my library (a node module).

In es5, i'll have done something like :

```
MyLib.Object.prototype.myNewMethod = function () {
}
```

In order to make

```
const o = new MyObject();
o.myNewMethod();
const o2 = new MySecondObject();
o2.myNewMethod();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why would you prefer modifying the library object over having an intermediate class? What is the advantage? Generally "monkey patching" things you do not own is considered bad practice.

Comment: I've edited my question. 
My objects does'nt extends the same library class. 
Take a look

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
// The library object class
class Object {
  myNewMethod() {}
}
```

Even with ES6, you can still use `Object.prototype`

```
Object.prototype.myNewMethod = function() {}
```

But the proper way is to let the original base class as it is, and use inheritance.

```
class Object1 extends Object {
  myNewMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: Not realy, doing this I have to change the code of the library. 
I'm searching for a way to add method in the library 'object' class from my code, using es6 syntax. 
In order to have the 'newMethod' in all my objects that have extended the 'Object1' class

Comment: do you have to use es6 syntax? why not just `YourClass.prototype.myMethod` ?

Comment: On the other hand, this is also a bad answer, patching a library is not a good idea, instead, extend your custom class with the methods you need.

Comment: i don't have to use es6 syntax. 
My curious side is searching a way to write this in es6

Comment: I have 10 differents class that extends the library object class, in all my class the newMethod will have to do exactly the same work. It's the reason why i'm searching a way to add it in the library 'Object' class i extends.

Comment: To be more precise, i'm working on a drawing software. 
I use a library that draw on canvas. 
Library has a basic object class and other shape classes (like rectangle, triangle circle) that extends the object class. 
Then i have my own shape class that extends the library shape class. 
I'd like to had a behavior for all my object. 
The way to do that is to add a method in the library object class. 
Just searching for a way to write this using es6 syntax.

Comment: Yes, then extend it once `class MyExtension` and use your extended version to extend the others, just by replacing the `Object` with `MyExtension`

Comment: There is nothing wrong to use `Object.prototype`. ES6 is a superset of ES5, that means, you can use it.

Comment: Just updated my question, which may not have been very clear. If there's no way to write it in es6 i'll use prototype notation.